# Как получить отдельные кадры анимированного gif?

Tags: c#, winforms, gif

Есть анимированный gif в файле.
Как из него извлечь отдельные кадры (Image) и вывести их в виде сетки?

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;

static IEnumerable<Image> Frames(Image gif) {
  var d = new FrameDimension(gif.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
  for (var i = 0; i < gif.GetFrameCount(d); i++) {
     gif.SelectActiveFrame(d, i);
     var ci = new Bitmap(gif.Width, gif.Height);
     using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(ci))
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(gif, 0, 0);
     yield return ci;
  }
}

var f1 = new Form() { Width = 450, Height = 250 };
var img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Temp\5-0.gif");
var t = new TableLayoutPanel() {
              Parent = f1,
              BackColor = Color.White,
              Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
              AutoSize = false,
              AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly
              };
int ci = 0, ri = 0;
foreach (var fi in Frames(img)) {
   var p = new PictureBox() { Image = fi, Parent = t };
   t.Controls.Add(p, ci, ri);
   if (++ci == 4) { ci = 0; ri++; }
}
f1.ShowDialog();
```

Для рис.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получим

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]